# Angular 2: variable value changed within dataservice call is not reflected on the page until you leave the page and return to it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am using Angular2 and displaying a variable on the page. The page has a button that I click and a data service is invoked. Inside the dataservice call, I change the value of the variable and expect the change to be reflected on the page. However, I still see the old value. Only when I click on another link and then come back to this page, do I see the new value reflected. Any changes to the variable that I make outside a dataservice call is reflected immediately. Only the changes within the dataservice call is not reflected: Below is some code snippet:

HTML template:

```
<button type="button" class="btn (click)="clickNextButton()">
    <span>save</span>  
</button>

{{text}}
```

Typescript class

```
export class ConfigComponent implements OnInit {
    public text = '';

    ..
    ..
    private clickNextButton(): void {
        this.text = 'abc;
        this.dataService.getConfig()
            .then((config: IConfig): void => {
            console.log('printed');
            this.text = 'xyz';
            console.log('printed..');
        });
    }
}
```

So, I click on the button and the value changes to abc on the page but it does not change to xyz. console logs are printed fine, so I know for sure that the code is reached. Why the changes I make to the variable inside the dataservice call not getting reflected on the page? How do I fix this issue?

Update:

This issue occurs only when the component is included and used in another component, as:

```
 <prod-setup
     ....
 </prod-setup>
```

When I change variable value in the dataService call of the main component, it changes and reflects fine on the view. Only when I change a variable in the Data Service call of the included component, it doesn't reflect on the UI. Any idea?

Comment: use chrome debug tools to get more information about the behavior.

Comment: try adding `resolve();` after `console.log('printed..');`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your async call is outside [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) thus not triggering the UI update (Angular optimizes the app performance running async calls outside zone).
You can put your code inside zone detection:

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';

export class ConfigComponent implements OnInit {
    public text = '';
    public constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

    ..
    ..
    private clickNextButton(): void {
        this.text = 'abc;
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.dataService.getConfig()
                .then((config: IConfig): void => {
                console.log('printed');               
                this.text = 'xyz';                             
                console.log('printed..');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue

Comment: All right. Try to change the call of angular zone run - I edited my answer and  `this.ngZone.run` is encompassing `this.dataService.getConfig()`

Comment: I added a section 'Update' under the original question. The issue seem more specific when I am changing a variable in an included component and not in the main  component. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you providing the service only once? I mean, are you providing `dataService` only in some main module which contains the views, i.e. `app.module.ts`?

Comment: yes, and infact this problem occurs even with code in setTimeout. Any variable set instantly is reflected on the UI. anything thats within a DataService call or setTimeout etc is not reflected (only when its an included component in the main component)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `resolve()` so the calling function gets notified and can perform any post processing.

```
private clickNextButton(): void {
        this.text = 'abc;
        this.dataService.getConfig()
            .then((config: IConfig): void => {
            console.log('printed');
            this.text = 'xyz';
            this.text = resolve();     

        });
    }
```

Another option would be to call another function that will set the value

```
     private clickNextButton(): void {
        this.text = 'abc;
        this.dataService.getConfig()
            .then((config: IConfig): void => {
            console.log('printed');
            this.text = 'xyz';
            this.text = resolve('xyz');
            this.setValue();     

        });
    }
    setValue(): void{
        this.text
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue

Comment: When I used resolve(), compiler complains that it cannot find resolve(). So, I had tried Promise.resolve() earlier. Is that what you meant when you said resolve()?

Comment: yes, it is `Promise.resolve()`. Does is it solved your issue ?

Comment: No, I tried both ways you mentioned but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @user1892775, if it works, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

is this.text of the dataservice not out of scope? 
ie, try :  private clickNextButton =(): void => {
could also setup message service that returns a message to the component when updated.

[angular 4 service cannot read property 'newService' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934718/angular-4-service-cannot-read-property-newservice-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment82858669_47934718)